# custom validation with conditions in yii

Tags: yii

sorry for the noob question, but I don't understand why it is not returning what im expecting. Basically, it is just looking to see whether user's start and end are between the dates that exists per the id, no?

```
public function date_range($attribute, $params)
{
    $model= Table::model();
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->addCondition('start_date < '.$this->start_date);
    $criteria->addCondition('end_date > '.$this->end_date);

    $record = $model->findAll($criteria);

    if($record==true)
    $this->addError('id', 'Item already exists within range.');

}
```

Comment: the condition looks alright, how are the results extracted different from expected?

Comment: It saves within the range... while i'm expecting the error. :/

Answer (score 0):

you can put the contents of this function in a better place like `beforeValidate()` and then return your error .

```
public function beforeValidate()
{

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->addCondition('start_date < '.$this->start_date);
    $criteria->addCondition('end_date > '.$this->end_date);

    $record = Table::model()->exist($criteria); // I checked for existance

    if(!empty($record)) // if there are records
    {
         $this->addError('id', 'Item already exists within range.');
         return false;
     }
    return parent::beforeValidate();//don't forget this line
}
```

Comment: It is still saving within range. :/

Comment: what is in `$this->start_date`?

Comment: the start date from the user... no?

Comment: I mean this is a type of datetime, timestring? BTW check for `<=` and `>=` for that and see if that works